# Force Unity game in folder to run windowed

Tags: unity-game-engine

There are multiple Unity games that I play that are only available as a .zip download so I have to run the exe from a folder. None of these have an option to change the resolution of the game. How can I force the exe to run in windowed (1440p)? Because I have a 4k monitor and my pc isn't that great, so games lag if they're not windowed 1440p or lower. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

So, for posterity, the other answer on this page is extremely incomplete, and is missing a very important argument. After creating a shortcut, you need to go to the line that says 'target' and add this to whatever other arguments have:

> -screen-fullscreen 0

This overrides the fullscreen setting and forces the game to launch in windowed mode. You then use -screen-width and -screen-height to adjust the window appropriately. Here's a full example:

> -screen-fullscreen 0 -screen-height 900 -screen-width 1600

I hope this helps any other people who arrive here from Google like I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line arguments: [Unity - Manual: Command line arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html)

Just create a shortcut, open it's properties and add the command line arguments

> -screen-height
> -screen-width

with the resolution of your choice.